# How can I connect mlab mongoDB on Heroku from local?

Tags: mongodb, heroku

When I was invited in heroku git, can I connect mLab mongoDB from local?
Otherwise Can I export DB to local?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can connect mlab. You can see the connection string details in the database dashboard page. You have to use the username password created on the DB. User credentials are available in the users tab. Refer to [doc](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/mongolab#using-mlab-s-admin-tools-for-mongodb)

[image]